# Closed as exact duplicate -> where is the solution?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

Mu question [Can I do an install onto a 4GB usb stick which is smaller than the recommended installation size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116051/can-i-do-full-install-on-4gb-usb-stick) was closed as exact duplicate with a url to possible duplicate answer.

Currently I have very specific conditions that stated in my question. Especially that I have **no hdd** and only **4GB stick** available.

I cannot find the solution in provided "possible duplicate" answer.

I admit that I am not so experienced Ubuntu user and working solution might be there but I cannot see it. Please help :-)

Comment: Would [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/17007/18612) not work for you? How many USB ports does your machine have?

Comment: No, this won't work because I cannot click continue as my stick size is less than 4.4GB.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid it's simply not possible to do the install you are requesting unless you got a larger target USB drive. The smallest size of Ubuntu you could install would require at least that amount of memory you have listed.

Comment: Well, I thought that was the case. All my findings pointed out that. And this was the reason why I created my question. **So is that a duplicate or not?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have revised your question and reopened it to clarify the points in the comments - specifically - how to squeeze the installation of Ubuntu onto a HDD or USB stick smaller than the recommended size.

However - I consider this as a possible duplicate of

[FULL install Ubuntu on 4GB USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55984/full-install-ubuntu-on-4gb-usb-drive)

I'll leave this to others as to whether this is actually a duplicate or not.

Comment: Thank you for that.