# What to do when I have a question closed for being the duplicate of another which has no solution that works for me?

Tags: discussion

I have [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/294461/47206) that was closed as duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/278912/47206) one, which has two answers. [One](https://askubuntu.com/a/278930/47206) is just a recommendation with no real use. [The definitive answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/278933/47206) indicates one solution, a program that has not represented a solution for me. I would like to know more: aren't there other similar programs? Cannot for the same purpose a more largely supported (default or well-known) program be used?

But any such question might be redirected to the older one. What to do now exactly?

---

I see that the motive of my question being closed is that "it already has an answer". But that answer expresses just the satisfaction of the author of the older question: me and my question are not content. I need a new answer, that the older question will not receive, as its definitive answer is already appointed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put that information in the actual question, with links to the old ones that you've tried, that way it's obvious to the community that you've tried them.

Basically, what you just posted here. :)

Comment: i imagined that this is a meta situation. a similar meta question [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2840/47206) got the main question reopened. i wander if an old reedited question gets the same automatic attention as the new one. mine may be opened and closed/merged after a solution.

Comment: you mean reedit my question? i thought you mean reedit the old one

Comment: Yeah. Add the information to your question so it's obvious that it's not a dupe

Comment: i have added that

Comment: What about adding a bounty to the original?

Comment: i will delete the question soon because now my main question is set as duplicate of a different question - so this doesnt make sense

Comment: @cipricus don't give up, It is an interesting question, but right now I feel that we don't have enough information to solve other than providing random "did you try this program, or this program..."

Answer (score 2):

There are many iso mounting programs, if mounting through a program or through ubuntu like the dupe suggested didn't work: I think you need to give specifics as to *what* program you are trying to mount and use in WINE, as the problem could be specific to that software. In order to diffrentiate between the two, this would also for sure make it not a dupe of that question - because now it would be about getting that software to work, not general iso/image mounting.

Details like format, what program made the image, maybe it is a WINE issue?

However, If you just want more alternatives to the same basic question, I suggest adding a bounty to the dupe.